# auto calculate without pressing a button the other value is come from the data base

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, calculator

```
<asp:Label ID="cost" runat="server" Text="Cost :" ></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Cost" runat="server" > </asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Request Quantity :"></asp:Label>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="amount" class="form-control" />
<asp:Label ID="totalcost" runat="server" Text="Total Cost :"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" ></asp:Label>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.amount').change(function () {
        var result = 0;
        $('.cost').each(function () {
            result += +$(this).val();
        });
        $('#Total').val(result);
    });
```

Hi I need to auto-calculate when I input any value to the TextBox 
Cost(any value that come from my database)*RequestQuantity = Total

Comment: You have multiple cost id's and you are calling `$('.cost').each()` as a class...

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblcost" runat="server" Text="Cost :" ></asp:Label> its just a label i change it already .. nothing happen

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Cost" runat="server" > </asp:Label> the value on this come from my database ...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling class to run .each function....

Your JQuery should be $('#amount') rather than .amount it will not trigger on change because your amount is an ID not a class

```
 $('.cost').
```

I don't see any class called .cost

Updated Answer here

```
<asp:Label ID="cost" runat="server" Text="Cost :" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="cost">10</asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Request Quantity :"></asp:Label>
    <input type="text" runat="server" id="amount" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="totalcost" runat="server" Text="Total Cost :"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" ></asp:Label>


     <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#amount').keyup(function () {

                 var result;
                 var quantity = $(this).val();
                 var costValue;

                 $('.cost').each(function () {
                     costValue = $(this).text();
                 });

                 result = parseFloat(costValue) * parseInt(quantity)

                 if (isNaN(result)) result = 0;

                 $('#Total').text(result);
             });
         });
    </script>
```

Comment: <input type="text" runat="server" id="cost" class="form-control" />

Comment: $('#amount').change(function () {
        var result = 0;
        $('#cost').each(function () {
            result += +$(this).val();
        });
        $('#Total').val(result);
    });

Comment: I will update the answer.. Because you are getting value from label you can't use .val() you must use .text() . I just mock up this. From what i see you only have 1 Cost above... So i just get the value from it without adding += $(this).text();

Comment: Forget to mention why i change your event to keyup. If you using onchange you need to unfocus the textbox then the jquery only trigger.

Comment: how can i post a picture in here ?? because its still not working

Comment: Can you edit your question with the latest code ? Your reputation is not enough to post a picture...

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Cost :" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="reqCos" runat="server"  CssClass="cost" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>

<asp:Label  ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Request Quantity :" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="amount" />

<asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="Total Cost :" Font-Bold="True" BorderStyle="Solid"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="reqtotal" runat="server"    BackColor="Silver" Height="14px" Width="55px"></asp:Label> <br />

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#amount').keyup(function () {

                   var result;
                   var quantity = $(this).val();
                   var costValue;

                   $('.cost').each(function () {
                       costValue = $(this).text();
                   });

                   result = parseFloat(costValue) * parseInt(quantity)

                   if (result == isNaN) result = 0;

                   $('#reqtotal').text(result);
               });
           });
    </script>

Comment: why i cant post it like you do? ... the value from the cost is coming from my database .. my system is ordering system like that

Comment: @JrDones I copied your code and paste in to my testing page is working fine. Do you include JQuery library in your web page ? Another thing is what is your Cost Value?

Comment: the cost value come from my database ... sometimes it has 1.50 , 1.5 ,9.9 something like that... yes i put my jquery at the top of my code

Comment: you mean your cost value is separated by comma ?
Cost : 1.50, 1.5, 9.9 or
Cost : 1.50

Comment: its not seperated by comma  ...  

Available Quantity: 10
Cost : 1.96 
Request Quantity: 
Total Cost: 

thats my output

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FC5061B28DF7832!5349&authkey=!AIoLoHD3PgvZnnk&ithint=folder%2caspx I uploaded my file here... Have a look see what you want to modified to make it work.... Is aspx and aspx.cs file..

Comment: my code behind is visual basic ... do i need to modify it also?

Comment: No need. That is just a mock up so you can try it out see the function is work

Comment: even i try to create new page

Comment: What browser are you using ? Is it in VM ? What OS ?